# Intersection of row names in dataframe (subset the data)?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset, intersect

Since `intersect` doesn't work with dataframes, I'm trying to use subset to create a subset of `dfA` with only data for which `dfA`'s row names match `dfB`'s row names. I should end up with 3000 rows because `dfA` has 5000 rows and `dfB` has 3000, and all of `dfB`’s row names exist in `dfA`’s row names.

The following just returns `dfA`'s column names without any data.

```
mysubset = subset(dfA, dfA[,0] %in% dfB[,0])
```

Comment: `dfA[which(rownames(dfA) %in% rownames(dfB)),]`

Comment: `dplyr::semi_join`

Comment: Also, there's no index zero in `R`, indices are 1-based. `dfA[,0]`and `dfB[,0]` do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rownames` function will give you access to the rownames, then the set comparison condition will do what you expected.

Example, using small data frames with some shared rownames

```
dfA <- data.frame(x = 1:5,
                  y = 6:10,
                  row.names = letters[1:5])
# Show dfA
dfA
  x  y
a 1  6
b 2  7
c 3  8
d 4  9
e 5 10


dfB <- data.frame(x = 1:5,
                  y = 6:10,
                  row.names = letters[3:7])

# Show dfB
dfB
  x  y
c 1  6
d 2  7
e 3  8
f 4  9
g 5 10
```

Solution

```
# Subset rows with matching rownames 

dfA[ rownames(dfA) %in% rownames(dfB), ]
  x  y
c 3  8
d 4  9
e 5 10
```

Comment: I chose this answer since it's economical; although, Masoud's answer works as well. I don't know why I forgot all about `rownames`; I must've been so focused on using `mydf[,0]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should get a subset based on `rownames` for both data.frames.

```
dfA[which(rownames(dfA) %in% rownames(dfB)),]
```

This checks which row names from `dfA` are in row names of `dfB` (`which`) and returns the indices to get the data in `dfA` (`dfA[...]`).

If you want to stick to your solution (which costs a bit more, computationally):

```
subset(dfA, rownames(dfA) %in% rownames(dfB))
```